# How do I define an int64 in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

`let i = 32` will give me a `int32`.

What if I want to define a `int64`?

Comment: No, `let i = 32` won't give you a `int32`, it will give you a `int`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
let i = 32L
```

(Postfix L for int64 literals introduced in Objective Caml 3.07)

and use module Int64: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Int64.html
You should really use google as well...

Comment: it is really hard to google such L postfix. what I got from google is just that int64 page

Comment: What I did was I just copy pasted the title of your question into Google search form. The first page I got was the documentation of Int64 module. Then I adjusted the search by adding 'example' to it.

Comment: It might also help to scan the contents and index of the OCaml manual. I went to the [contents page](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual001.html) and searched for int64. The answer showed up instantly.

Comment: I will dissent a little here by stating that I think it's fine to ask relatively easy to google questions here. Answers on stackoverflow are much easier to find (even with google) then a man page. They also come with a lot of interesting related info usually.

Comment: I agree to some extent - it depends on specific case. That's why I didn't downvote the question but answered on it.

Answer (score 5):

`let i = 32` will give you a value of type `int` and not `int32`.

You can obtain a `int64` value by adding a L after the number as pointed out by piokuc and user1034081, But I am not sure that's what you want to do. Why do you want `int64`?

OCaml has an internal representation for integers that is different from other languages and it store them on 31 or 63 bits (depending on your architecture) because it needs an extra bit for the GC. I you don't have a very good reason to use `int64` (i.e. you want to use C code in OCaml or OCaml code in C), use the `int` type.

Comment: I am actually writing a bson encoder/decoder in ocaml, which requires int32 and int64. http://bsonspec.org/#/specification

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the postfix 'L' for int64:

```
let i = 32L
```

leads to: val i : int64 = 32L

Comment: let i = 32l will lead to int32